# Proper usage of 'if so'

Tags: grammar, so

I want to know if this sentence is grammatically correct.

*Is there anyone else who have access to admin panel?
If so, please provide us all ip addresses from all users in order to monitor your website traffic.*

Answer (score 3):

Everything is fine with *if so*, though the sentences need a little bit of work:

> Is there anyone else who **has** access to **the** admin panel? If so, please provide us **with** all **of the** **IP** addresses **of** all **of the** users in order **for us to be able** to monitor your website traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Or as I suggested on EL&U

> Could you please find someone with access to the admin panel, who can provide us with the IP addresses of all of the users in order for us to monitor your website traffic?

Answer (score 0):

"if so" is just like "if (true)"{...} :P